# Storing user information in session or pull from mysql?

Tags: php, performance, session, authentication

**Option 1:
Upon login, populate SESSION with basic users info (name, userid, account permissions, etc.)**

- Pro: Usually none of the user information changes, so there is no need for a database call. Since SESSION is already being called, it might as well store information there.
- Con: When user information is changed in the database, a session update must occur

**Option 2:
Store only uid, pull information every time**

- Pro: No issue of session updates. Information is always current.
- Con: MySQL queries for users data (users basic info, permissions, etc.)

I've seen some posts that claim the session method is also faster than MySQL (though I doubt it would make any real difference). 
Question: What's probably the best way to go, and why? My instincts say #2...

Comment: Pick option 2 and add some security functions. Session hijacking is serious business.

Comment: Charlotte, thanks for your thoughts. Do you have a reason for picking #2? Session hijacking is a separate matter.

Comment: Just google "php session hijacking". The topic "XSS" is also interesting.

Comment: I'm well aware of them both. Session hijacking can occur in both option 1 and 2 of my question, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you do. Both methods have pro and cons. And the developers are only the ones who are worrying about that, the users don't really care. As long as you implement the method you choose right, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @charlotte I don't think Caleb is addressing this from a user experience point of view, but from a performance/security point of view. We are the only ones 'worrying' about that because it's our job, to ensure our users are protected

Answer (score 0):

Load your data into a session (no point in hammering your database for mostly static info), and if there's an update to the database, update your session at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of both, load the data which can only be change by user (name or any personal information) in the session and fetch data (e.g permissions) which can be changes by other users (e.g. admin) from the data base.

Comment: Good point. I will be keeping track of sessions in MySQL as well to prohibit simultaneous logins, hacking, stats, etc. If an admin adjusts a user, then it will mark that session as *need to update*.